# How is the events count calculated in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, logstash, spark-streaming

I am using two logstash output plugins : elasticsearch and tcp to spark streaming, mu update interval is 1 mn. The number of events received in an interval is not the same in elasticsearch and spark streaming UI (Input Size). I would like to know if spark streaming calculates the number of events based on the number of lines received , or is it done in another way. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it is related to the window size :|

Comment: No, it is too small to be for the window , it is half of the events displayed in elasticsearch, but the threre is no contradiction in tha aggregated informations given by spark streaming

Comment: I had the same problem earlier.  There is a patch on Spark which fixes this. See github.com/apache/spark/pull/13259